# Loop through dynamic DataSet and insert Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

I have a DataTable in C# that I need to insert into a table. The DataTable is completely dynamic (Columns are not pre-defined). I inserted this DataTable row by row using C# code but because it is inefficient I am sending the DataTable bulk into an SQL Stored Procedure. I need the Stored Procedure to loop through the bulk, insert row by row, and return the set of invalid data.

**C# code:**

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = getDBConnection();
SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "[dbo].[saveDataIntoTable]";

SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();

//The parameter for the SP must be of SqlDbType.Structured
parameter.ParameterName = "@Sample";
parameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
parameter.Value = dataTable;

command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(row.ItemArray);
            if (row.ItemArray[0] == null)
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Remove(row);
            }
        }

SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);

//handling the dt DataTable here
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```sql
USE [DATABASE_NAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[saveDataIntoTable]
(
    -- which accepts one table value parameter. It should be noted that   the parameter is readonly
    @Sample As [dbo].[SampleUserData] Readonly
)
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY

    Insert  Into    USER(USER_ID,EMAIL,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_HINT,PWD_CHANGED_DATE,
        CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE,STATUS,VERSION,VALIDATE)
        Select USER_ID, EMAIL,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_HINT,PWD_CHANGED_DATE,
        CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE,STATUS,VERSION,VALIDATE From @Sample

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    Select USER_ID, EMAIL,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_HINT,PWD_CHANGED_DATE,
        CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE,STATUS,VERSION,VALIDATE From @Sample 
END CATCH
END
```

**I used a User-defined Table Type for the Stored Procedure:**

```sql
-- Create a table data type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SampleUserData] As Table
(
        --This type has structure similar to the DB table           
        USER_ID Nvarchar(20) ,
        EMAIL Nvarchar(50),
        PASSWORD Nvarchar(100),

        PASSWORD_HINT Nvarchar(20),
        PWD_CHANGED_DATE date,
        CREATED_BY Nvarchar(20),

        CREATED_DATE date,
        UPDATED_BY Nvarchar(20),
        UPDATED_DATE date,
        STATUS Nvarchar(20),
        VERSION Int,
        VALIDATE Nvarchar(10)

);
```

Right now, my Stored Procedure inserts the whole bulk of data at once. When an exception occurs, it returns the whole DataSet (I do not know how to separate the rows).

PS: If there is any other method for the above scenario which is easier, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the same as your stored procedure one line at a time:
This was written for SQL Server 2005

```sql
BEGIN
--I'm only using your first three columns in this example
DECLARE @USER_ID as Nvarchar(20);
DECLARE @Email as Nvarchar(20);
DECLARE @Password as Nvarchar(20);
DECLARE @SampleCursor as CURSOR;

SET @SampleCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT USER_ID, EMAIL, PASSWORD
 FROM  @Sample;
OPEN @SampleCursor;
--Can't insert directly into table from table variable so save as scalar variable first
FETCH NEXT FROM @SampleCursor INTO @USER_ID, @Email, @Password;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
FETCH NEXT FROM @SampleCursor INTO @USER_ID, @Email, @Password;
BEGIN TRY
--then insert scalar variables into table
INSERT INTO USER (USER_ID, Email, Password) VALUES( @USER_ID, @Email, @Password)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT  @USER_ID, @Email, @Password
END CATCH
END

CLOSE @SampleCursor;
DEALLOCATE @SampleCursor;
END
```

Comment: Thanks this has the right approach but how can I use something like this:
    SET @SampleCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM  @Sample;

without selecting a specific set of columns. The reason is that, even though I set the column names specifically in the question, i don't the column names in the runtime.

Comment: So, because the columns are dynamic, I cannot use this:

    DECLARE USER_ID as Nvarchar(20);
    DECLARE Email as Nvarchar(20);
    DECLARE Password as Nvarchar(20);

Comment: What about creating the stored procedure dynamically in C# then executing it?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zxsa8hkf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: This is an ASP.NET project so I don't think I can create Stored Procedures from c# code to assemble in the Database.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. Just insert your source table one line at a time using TOP(1). The solution below creates a table temporarily so your source table isn't deleted.

```
--create copy of source table
SELECT * INTO TempTbl FROM Source_Table
--loop through temp table
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TempTbl)
BEGIN
--insert first line of temp table into destination table
BEGIN TRY 
INSERT INTO [USER] SELECT TOP (1) * FROM TempTbl
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT TOP(1) FROM TempTbl
END CATCH
--remove inserted line from temp table
DELETE TOP (1) FROM TempTbl
END
DROP TABLE TempTbl
```

Update.

This works for me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SOProc 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Source_Table_Name sysname = '' 
AS
BEGIN
EXEC(
'SELECT * INTO TempTbl FROM ' +  @Source_Table_Name)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TempTbl)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY 
INSERT INTO User_Table SELECT TOP (1) * FROM TempTbl
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT TOP(1) * FROM TempTbl
END CATCH
DELETE TOP (1) FROM TempTbl
END
DROP TABLE TempTbl
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be the right approach, but how should I edit the sql to insert data to the temporary table if the Source_Table is a parameter: like `SELECT * INTO TempTbl FROM @SourceTableParam`?

I tried using `EXEC('SELECT * INTO TempTbl FROM' +  @TableNameParam)` but the other references failed because the `TempTbl` parameter is not declared

Comment: Execute the above with the table name as parameter. Note the whitespace after 'SELECT * INTO TempTbl FROM

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a where clause to validate the data

```sql
-- insert valid data
insert into [USER] (USER_ID,EMAIL,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_HINT,PWD_CHANGED_DATE,
                  CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE,STATUS,VERSION,VALIDATE)
select USER_ID, EMAIL,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_HINT,PWD_CHANGED_DATE,
       CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE,STATUS,VERSION,VALIDATE
from @Sample
where USER_ID is not null

-- select invalid data
select USER_ID, EMAIL,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_HINT,PWD_CHANGED_DATE,
       CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE,STATUS,VERSION,VALIDATE
from @Sample
where USER_ID is null
```

An example of a more detailed validation check

```
select USER_ID, EMAIL,PASSWORD,PASSWORD_HINT,PWD_CHANGED_DATE,
       CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_DATE,STATUS,VERSION,VALIDATE
from @Sample S
where USER_ID is not null
and EMAIL is not null
and PASSWORD is not null -- etc
-- check record is not duplicate
and not exists (select 1 from [USER] U where U.USER_ID = S.USER_ID)
and isnumeric(USER_ID)
```

Comment: Yeah but how can I use this to check data-type validations, null validations, duplicate fields all at once? That is the reason I used a try catch block.

Comment: @DilangaThalpegama What do you mean by duplicate fields? Null validation can certainly be handled in a where clause, datatype validations to some extent also and duplicate records too.

Comment: I cannot use where clauses because as I said the DataSet is **dynamically generated**. I do not know the column names or any of the other constraints. That is the reason for using a try catch block. I'm trying to use a cursor to loop through the DataSet received as a parameter. Can you help me in that?

Comment: Even if the DataSet is dynamically generated, the table type is 'fixed', if you don't know the column names how did you write your current SP?

Comment: What I do is, I dynamically generate table types when the table is created. I keep a reference to that table type when inserting to the related table.

When inserting, I do something like this:

     `Insert Into USER
     Select * From @Sample`

Where `@Sample` is the Table Type parameter.